# Angularjs component - transclusion with passing data

Tags: angularjs

Hello I would like to create component with transclusion and passing data from child to parent component.
My idea is here:

**List component template:**

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.list"><ng-transclude></ng-transclude></li>
</ul>
```

**Using**

```
<list-component>
  <strong>{{itemFromComponent.name}}<strong>
  //how to get item from list-component to here??
</list-component>
```

Please show me how to pass current item from component to parent to be able to see it. Thanks

Comment: This wouldn't even work.  You have this completely backwards.  `list-component` doesn't have a *single* `item`, it has a list;  you can't transclude the inner HTML into multiple blocks like this.  in other words, putting `ng-transclude` inside `ng-repeat` isn't valid.

Comment: `ng-transclude ` inside  `ng-repeat` works correctly. But of course show allways same data. I thought it might work as in angular2 (in component `<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template; context: {$implicit: d}"></ng-container>` and in parent: `<component><ng-template #columnTemplate let-v let-data="data"></component>`)

Comment: Right, you are making my point.  Angular 1.x doesn’t “expand” the transclusion multiple times, so you always get the same data.  You cannot, in the current 1.x design, make multiple transclusions responsive to the inner template data.

Comment: its not good. I would like to create universal component for select box which load data from API and `option` would be inserted from parent. now I have to create a new component for each data source.

Comment: That’s not even the same as what you are asking about in the question at all.  What does an option list have to do with transcluded html?  This is starting to feel like an xy question, where you are asking about your solution (transclusion) instead of your problem.  There is probably a way to achieve your goal, if you ask about that, and show true code examples, instead....

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside components, the `ng-transclude` directive adds a child scope.

To access the component scope, prepend transcluded variables with `$parent`:

```
<list-component list="[1,3,8]">
  LIST {{$parent.$ctrl.list}}<br/>
  ITEM <strong>{{$parent.item}}</strong>
</list-component>
```

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/6hsjvZP2QmfyS0o1RGLk?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.component("listComponent", {
  transclude: true,
  bindings: {list: '<'},
  template: `
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.list">
    $index={{$index}}<br/>
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
  </li>
</ul>
`
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <list-component list="[1,3,8]">
      LIST {{$parent.$ctrl.list}}<br/>
      ITEM <strong>{{$parent.item}}</strong>
    </list-component>
  </body>
```

Comment: Phew, It's been one hour that I was looking for a solution that neat. Thanks a lot :-D

Comment: I understand that using `$parent` is not always the best option as hierarchy can change, but in this case where the transclusion is meant to only be used within the component `$parent` really is the solution people should reach for especially if they are just wanting access to component variables.